# Javascript month calendar showing weeks only

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

I'm looking for a calendar that can show x amount of months and then display the week numbers in those months as well as displaying events, as seen below.

[image: Calendar]

The blue dotted line is todays date and there can be multiple events that have a start and end date.

This is what I tried so far http://jsfiddle.net/vc1f3f4x/1/ - the problem is it is showing 4 months instead of only 3 and I haven't even gotten to the events yet.

[image]

```
var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
                  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
                 ];

var data = new Object();

data.Months = {};
data.Weeks = new Array();

var start = new Date();
var end = new Date();
start.setDate(1);

end.setMonth(start.getMonth() + 3);

var weekNumber = getWeekNumber(start);
var currentYear = start.getYear();

for (var dt = start; start <= end; dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 7)) {
    if (dt.getYear() > currentYear) {
        currentYear = dt.getYear();
        weekNumber = 1;
    }

    weekNumber++;

    var id = dt.getMonth() + "_" + dt.getYear();

    data.Months[id] = monthNames[dt.getMonth()];
    data.Weeks.push(weekNumber);
}

// Run through each month and add it to dom
for (var month in data.Months) {
    $(".Content").append("<div class='Month'>" + data.Months[month] + "</div>");
}

// Then run through each week and add it to dom
for (var i = 0; i < data.Weeks.length; i++) {
    $(".Content").append("<div class='Week'>" + data.Weeks[i] + "</div>");
}

function getWeekNumber(d) {
    // Copy date so don't modify original
    d = new Date(+d);
    d.setHours(0, 0, 0);
    // Set to nearest Thursday: current date + 4 - current day number
    // Make Sunday's day number 7
    d.setDate(d.getDate() + 4 - (d.getDay() || 7));
    // Get first day of year
    var yearStart = new Date(d.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
    // Calculate full weeks to nearest Thursday
    var weekNo = Math.ceil((((d - yearStart) / 86400000) + 1) / 7);
    // Return array of year and week number
    return weekNo;
}
```

Is there a component that can do this for me or do I need to create it from scratch?

EDIT: I just realized my code doesn't handle months where there are 5 weeks in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is showing four because you are doing Current Month PLUS 3 which is infact 4 months.

You are setting your start date to first of current month and then adding 3 to it to set the end date's month.

I recommend using `moment.js` for doing date operations, I find it very useful for doing anything with Dates.